# Force Spotlight to index specific Library folders

Tags: macos, spotlight, library

How can I get Spotlight to index a directory in the system's Library folder?

I'm trying to get Spotlight running 10.10.3 to index some folders in the `Macintosh HD/Library` folder. I'm not getting any search results from these folders so it appears Spotlight is not searching/indexing them. The folder can be found at:

```
Macintosh HD/Library/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/htdocs/
```

I am getting search results for other Library folders, such as my web root folder at:

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/
```

Is there a way to force Spotlight to also index the `Library/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/htdocs` folder as well?

(I want to index FileMaker Server's web root folder that I referenced above. I will not be indexing the FileMaker Server database folders as I have excluded those from Spotlight)

Answer (score 0):

Spotlight is already indexing those files and folders. You can check for the file names.

The actual problem is that the importer is ignoring the "code" portion of the files so the strings you want to find are not matching.

```
mdfind -name fmwebd_home.html
```

If you copy a html file to your desktop, you can play with editing them to include strings inside the body of the html - and see if spotlight can find things. Junk names like ZZtestZZ are easy to make up that don't return other spotlight matches.

```
mdfind  -interpret ZZtestZZ
```

Also, if you search in Spotlight graphically, you might want to save smart folders/searches that include the system files since they are normally suppressed from default searches.

Comment: Hi @bmike I just did a search for a series of file names that exist in the Macintosh HD/Library/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/htdocs/sample/ and Spotlight didn't find any of them, so it doesn't appear to be search this directory. Same result for the contents of files - nothing found. I have a backup of the directory on a USB drive and Spotlight finds the files and contents every time however.